# Missing storage space after asahi linux uninstall

Tags: macos

I've tried running asahi linux on my 2020 macbook air (M1), but after deinstallation I'm missing +-70 GB of storage. This is the size of the asahi linux partition, but I can't figure out how to create a new partition from that free space. When I run `disutil list` I get the following result:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         251.0 GB   disk0
   1:             Apple_APFS_ISC ⁨⁩                        524.3 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         174.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                        EFI ⁨EFI - ASAHI⁩             500.2 MB   disk0s3
                    (free space)                         70.5 GB    -
   4:        Apple_APFS_Recovery ⁨⁩                        5.4 GB     disk0s4
```

Does anyone know how I can create a partition from that free space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to delete partition #3 and then you should be able to grow partition #2.  I believe this link will give you the information you are looking for:

[How to remove a partition with terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304882/how-to-remove-a-partition-with-terminal)